# obs-studio duplicate setting panels at bottom glitch

Tags: obs-studio

I recorded 100+ educational videos last year using OBS on ubuntu so I generally have a decent idea how to use the program. Having not used it for a hot minute, I decided to run it to setup a new project I'm working on. When I did each of the panels at the bottom were doubled. Not just controls, but audio, sources, scene transitions, etc and they are overlapping each-other in a rather glitchy fashion. This renders the program useless for me.

[image: Image of the glitch]

So I figured it was probably a config file mismatch from different versions. I decided to bork the config and $rm -rf .config/obs-studio and restarted. Same result. This was the ppa version. So I apt purged it, cleared the user config again, removed the ppa and installed the debian package version.

Same results! So I again cleared the config purged and tried the snap version. This again had the same results.

I ran it from the terminal to see if there were any glaring errors. The Failed to load 'en-US' text for module: 'decklink-ouput-ui.so' warning stuck out but apparently is not a problem for most people. I only did this in the debian repo version

```
$obs 
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark.qss
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark.qss
info: CPU Name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9900K CPU @ 3.60GHz
info: CPU Speed: 3600.000MHz
info: Physical Cores: 8, Logical Cores: 16
info: Physical Memory: 32037MB Total, 25550MB Free
info: Kernel Version: Linux 5.13.0-28-generic
info: Distribution: "Ubuntu" "20.04"
info: Window System: X11.0, Vendor: The X.Org Foundation, Version: 1.20.13
info: Portable mode: false
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark/no_sources.svg
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Dark/no_sources.svg
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_advAudioProps_clicked()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_advAudioProps_destroyed()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_actionGridMode_triggered()
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_program_customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)
info: OBS 25.0.3+dfsg1-2 (linux)
info: ---------------------------------
info: ---------------------------------
info: audio settings reset:
    samples per sec: 44100
    speakers:        2
info: ---------------------------------
info: Initializing OpenGL...
info: Loading up OpenGL on adapter ATI Technologies Inc. AMD Radeon Pro W5500
info: OpenGL loaded successfully, version 3.3.14756 Core Profile Context FireGL, shading language 4.60
info: ---------------------------------
info: video settings reset:
    base resolution:   1920x1080
    output resolution: 1280x720
    downscale filter:  Bicubic
    fps:               30/1
    format:            NV12
    YUV mode:          601/Partial
info: NV12 texture support not available
info: Audio monitoring device:
    name: Default
    id: default
info: ---------------------------------
warning: Failed to load 'en-US' text for module: 'decklink-ouput-ui.so'
libDeckLinkAPI.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
warning: A DeckLink iterator could not be created.  The DeckLink drivers may not be installed
info: No blackmagic support
error: os_dlopen(libnvidia-encode.so.1->libnvidia-encode.so.1): libnvidia-encode.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

info: FFMPEG VAAPI supported
info: VLC found, VLC video source enabled
info: ---------------------------------
info:   Loaded Modules:
info:     vlc-video.so
info:     text-freetype2.so
info:     rtmp-services.so
info:     obs-x264.so
info:     obs-transitions.so
info:     obs-outputs.so
info:     obs-filters.so
info:     obs-ffmpeg.so
info:     linux-v4l2.so
info:     linux-pulseaudio.so
info:     linux-jack.so
info:     linux-decklink.so
info:     linux-capture.so
info:     linux-alsa.so
info:     image-source.so
info:     frontend-tools.so
info:     decklink-ouput-ui.so
info: ---------------------------------
info: ==== Startup complete ===============================================
error: Service '' not found
info: No scene file found, creating default scene
info: All scene data cleared
info: ------------------------------------------------
info: pulse-input: Server name: 'pulseaudio 13.99.1'
info: pulse-input: Audio format: s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels
info: pulse-input: Started recording from 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor'
info: pulse-input: Server name: 'pulseaudio 13.99.1'
info: pulse-input: Audio format: s16le, 44100 Hz, 1 channels
info: pulse-input: Started recording from 'alsa_input.usb-AONI_ELECTRONIC_CO.LTD_NexiGo_N930AF_FHD_webcam_20200924003-02.mono-fallback'
info: Switched to scene 'Scene'
warning: Failed to glob scene collections
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/images/overflow.png
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/images/overflow.png
warning: [rtmp-services plugin] Update file 'services.json' (version 188) rejected
warning: [rtmp-services plugin] Successfully updated package (version 188)
info: adding 46 milliseconds of audio buffering, total audio buffering is now 46 milliseconds (source: Mic/Aux)

info: ==== Shutting down ==================================================
info: Switched to scene '(null)'
info: pulse-input: Stopped recording from 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor'
info: pulse-input: Got 2850 packets with 613510 frames
info: pulse-input: Stopped recording from 'alsa_input.usb-AONI_ELECTRONIC_CO.LTD_NexiGo_N930AF_FHD_webcam_20200924003-02.mono-fallback'
info: pulse-input: Got 1573 packets with 695766 frames
info: All scene data cleared
info: ------------------------------------------------
info: Freeing OBS context data
info: [Scripting] Total detached callbacks: 0
info: == Profiler Results =============================
info: run_program_init: 12523.4 ms
info:  ┣OBSApp::AppInit: 1.303 ms
info:  ┃ ┗OBSApp::InitLocale: 0.462 ms
info:  ┗OBSApp::OBSInit: 12463 ms
info:    ┣obs_startup: 21.155 ms
info:    ┗OBSBasic::OBSInit: 12407.3 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitBasicConfig: 0.192 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetAudio: 0.046 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetVideo: 33.599 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitOBSCallbacks: 0.002 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitHotkeys: 0.02 ms
info:      ┣obs_load_all_modules: 45.399 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(decklink-ouput-ui.so): 0.354 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(frontend-tools.so): 20.834 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(image-source.so): 0.003 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-alsa.so): 0.001 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-capture.so): 0.186 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-decklink.so): 0.06 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-jack.so): 0.001 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-pulseaudio.so): 0.001 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(linux-v4l2.so): 0.001 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-ffmpeg.so): 0.127 ms
info:      ┃ ┃ ┗nvenc_check: 0.115 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-filters.so): 0.017 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-outputs.so): 0.001 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-transitions.so): 0.006 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(obs-x264.so): 0.001 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(rtmp-services.so): 0.098 ms
info:      ┃ ┣obs_init_module(text-freetype2.so): 0.021 ms
info:      ┃ ┗obs_init_module(vlc-video.so): 0.549 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::ResetOutputs: 0.071 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::CreateHotkeys: 0.017 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitService: 0.75 ms
info:      ┣OBSBasic::InitPrimitives: 0.057 ms
info:      ┗OBSBasic::Load: 4.061 ms
info: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=0.042 ms, median=0.228 ms, max=8.542 ms, 99th percentile=3.239 ms, 100% below 25 ms
info: audio_thread(Audio): min=0 ms, median=0.019 ms, max=0.111 ms, 99th percentile=0.091 ms
info: obs_graphics_thread(33.3333 ms): min=0.121 ms, median=0.48 ms, max=12.162 ms, 99th percentile=2.72 ms, 100% below 33.333 ms
info:  ┣tick_sources: min=0 ms, median=0.002 ms, max=6.245 ms, 99th percentile=0.005 ms
info:  ┣output_frame: min=0.056 ms, median=0.06 ms, max=0.189 ms, 99th percentile=0.121 ms
info:  ┃ ┗gs_context(video->graphics): min=0.056 ms, median=0.06 ms, max=0.189 ms, 99th percentile=0.121 ms
info:  ┃   ┣render_video: min=0.03 ms, median=0.033 ms, max=0.145 ms, 99th percentile=0.073 ms
info:  ┃   ┃ ┗render_main_texture: min=0.028 ms, median=0.03 ms, max=0.141 ms, 99th percentile=0.069 ms
info:  ┃   ┗gs_flush: min=0.017 ms, median=0.019 ms, max=0.044 ms, 99th percentile=0.036 ms
info:  ┗render_displays: min=0.007 ms, median=0.399 ms, max=11.929 ms, 99th percentile=2.087 ms
info: =================================================
info: == Profiler Time Between Calls ==================
info: obs_hotkey_thread(25 ms): min=25.109 ms, median=25.365 ms, max=33.602 ms, 94.6117% within ±2% of 25 ms (0% lower, 5.38827% higher)
info: obs_graphics_thread(33.3333 ms): min=33.188 ms, median=33.334 ms, max=33.479 ms, 100% within ±2% of 33.333 ms (0% lower, 0% higher)
info: =================================================
info: Number of memory leaks: 1
```

The only major thing that has changed that I can think of is I switched to using the AMD driver for my AMD Radeon Pro W5500. That's what I will try next if I can't figure anything else out. I hope you understand that switching my graphics subsystem is not something I do lightly. So I'm hoping someone can think of something else it might be or confirm other people without the silly graphics drivers are getting a similar problem.

Cheers

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention. If you undock the settings panel from the bottom there is only one and the duplicates disappear.

**Updates:**

- Uninstalled amdgpu-pro drivers this morning and problem still persits.